# Read CSV file, manipulate columns and append result in new column. Python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, cartesian

I am having some trouble attempting to manipulate a CSV file and appending the results to a new column.

Essentially I have a csv file (delimited ;) with 5 columns currently (of Cartesian coords [X, Y] and components [dX, dY], and magnitude/ length). I wish to add the result of some equations, which differ depending on the value of my Cartesian components, to a 6th column in this csv file (the angle).

Thus far my code is this (the maths is correct [hopefully], it's just the appending that I'm having trouble with):

```
import csv, math
with open("mydata.csv", "rb") as f:
vectors = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")

    for col in vectors:
        x = float(col[0])
        y = float(col[1])
        dX = float(col[2])
        dY = float(col[3])
        magnitude = float(col[4])

        if dX > 0 and dY > 0:
            comp = dY/dX
            theta = math.degrees(math.atan(comp))
            angle = 90 - theta
        elif dX > 0 and dY < 0:
            comp = dY/dX
            theta = math.degrees(math.atan(comp))
            angle = 90 + theta
        elif dX < 0 and dY > 0:
            comp = dX/dY
            theta = math.degrees(math.atan(comp))
            angle = 360 - theta
        elif dX < 0 and dY < 0:
            comp = dY/dX
            theta = math.degrees(math.atan(comp))
            angle = 270 - theta
```

So essentially, I want to add the `angle` variable to a 6th column, for the correct line of my csv file.

I tried to create a new list and append (e.g.):

```
angles = []
...
angles.append(col)
angles.append(angle)
```

However, as you may have guessed I ended up with a line like this:

```
[[x, y, dX, dY, magnitude], angle]
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is too late as a solution has already been accepted, but the simplest way to solve the  problem is to write the newly-constructed row directly to the output csv file without creating an intermediate list.

You could write something like:

```
import csv, math

with open("mydata.csv", "rb") as f,\
     open("newdata.csv", "wb") as g:
        vectors = csv.reader(f, delimiter=";")
        writer = csv.writer(g, delimiter=";")
        for row in vectors:
            # use destructuring
            x, y, dX, dY, magnitude = map(float, row)

            if dX > 0 and dY > 0:
            #<snip>

            # at this stage you can write directly to the output
            # file.
            writer.writerow([x, y, dX, dY, magnitude, angle])
```

Comment: Whilst I accepted Martijn's solution - I believe this more efficiently solves the problem. Many thanks.

Comment: @MACooperr: This solves the problem in much the same way, actually. Neither is more efficient than the other, in any case. Not that I am begrudging superjump the accept here. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I suppose this is true! I can only apologise! Thank you both for your help. With the initial solution you provided I had trouble writing to csv whilst maintaining the original columns (it presented as one long list); however, this is likely due to my own ineptitude, rather than your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`col` is a list itself, so you'd *extend* `angles`:

```
angles.extend(col)
angles.append(angle)
```

where `list.extend()` copies over the elements into the `angles` list, rather than add a single reference to the `col` list object.

If all you do is produce a new row with one value added, just re-use `col` and append to it directly:

```
col.append(angle)
```

and write that to your output CSV file.

`col` is misnamed, really, I'd call it `row` instead.

Answer (score 0):

since `col` is *list* . u can just copy list items to angles and append it

```
angles=col[:]
angles.append(angle)
```